# How do I connect to asterisk server located in Windows 7 VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, asterisk

I have MS Windows 7. In that I installed VirtualBox and in that I installed Ubuntu.
In Ubuntu, I installed the Asterisk server. How can I connect to Asterisk server with Windows 7 applications?

---

no i added any external ip,defaultly the virtualbox generating ip address,in virtualbox you try commnd ifconfig/ipconfig then you find it

Comment: what is you purpose here? Are you testing, or what ?

Comment: no i want the solution

Comment: Have you assigned an IP address to the ubuntu virtual box? is it different from the IP address assigned to the windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the Bridged Adapter in the network type. That way your virtual machine will have its own IP and you can use that.
Read [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-network-sharing.html)